# Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException: Unable to locate view 'index.cshtml'

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

Experiencing the issue described here https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1528

Specifically, even though I am including Razor View Engine as per what I understand to be correct configuration, it doesn't always work.  Self-hosted.

Oddly, am not experiencing any issue on my Mac (Mono/Xamarin specific build) or 2 test machines (windows/windows build) - they work perfectly fine - but 2 other test machines (windows/windows build) do experience the issue.

Having difficulty pinpointing why that would be the case

Using .NET 4.5

Definitely have the RAZOR engine DLL present, and even force-referenced in the bootstrapper (and no exceptions are thrown)

Any clues?  Thank you!

EDIT 1: Here is the full stack trace, as requested.  I've subsequently changed it to explicit 'index.cshtml' but the error reported is basically the same (you just see .cshtml after index in the message).  Note the lack of cshtml as a supported view extension

```
Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! ---> Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException:     Unable to locate view 'index'
Currently available view engine extensions: sshtml,html,htm
Locations inspected: views/Home/index-en-US,views/Home/index,Home/index-en-US,Home/index,views/index-en-US,views/index,index-en-US,index
Root path: XXX
If you were expecting raw data back, make sure you set the 'Accept'-header of the request to correct format, for example 'application/json'
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.DefaultViewFactory.GetRenderedView(String viewName, Object model, ViewLocationContext viewLocationContext)
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.DefaultViewFactory.RenderView(String viewName, Object model, ViewLocationContext viewLocationContext)
   at Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.ViewProcessor.Process(MediaRange requestedMediaRange, Object model, NancyContext context)
   at Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.DefaultResponseNegotiator.NegotiateResponse(IEnumerable`1 compatibleHeaders, NegotiationContext negotiationContext, NancyContext context)
   at Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.DefaultResponseNegotiator.CreateResponse(IList`1 compatibleHeaders, NegotiationContext negotiationContext, NancyContext context)
   at Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.DefaultResponseNegotiator.NegotiateResponse(Object routeResult, NancyContext context)
   at Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass9.b__5(Task`1 completedTask)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook(NancyContext context, ErrorPipeline pipeline, Exception ex)
```

Comment: That exception contains information about where Nancy tried to find index.hrml. Could you look at that and add the information to the question?

Comment: Something wrong: "Currently available view engine extensions: sshtml,html,htm"

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have valid razor config
https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine